# Use React-Redux in coding apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, umd

Q How to use configureStore on an offline coding app?

I am trying to use react-redux in an android coding app. And I included the umd code like this:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/babel.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/react.development.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/react-dom.development.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/redux.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/react-redux.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/redux-toolkit.umd.js'></script>
<script type='text/babel' src='js/app/app.js'></script>
```

I can use `<Provider>` and `createStore()` and `combineReducers()` by prefixing them with Redux like `Redux.createStore()`. The problem is I cannot use `configureStore()`.

I tried `configureStore`

`Redux.configureStore`

`ReduxToolkit.configureStore`

and more, either `configureStore()` is not defined or the module doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Getting Started](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started#an-existing-app) documentation it appears to be on the global window object.

> It is also available as a precompiled UMD package that defines a
> `window.RTK` global variable. The UMD package can be used as a [`<script>`
> tag](https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js) directly.

It looks like `configureStore` could be accessed as

```js
window.RTK.configureStore
```

or maybe just

```js
RTK.configureStore
```